# Proper Use of IPC::Run in Perl

Tags: perl

I'm trying to run IPC::Run as described in https://metacpan.org/pod/IPC::Run

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings FATAL => 'all';
use feature 'say';
use autodie qw(:all);
use IPC::Run qw(run timeout);

my ($out, $err);
## First,a command to run:
my @cat = qw( cat );

## Using run() instead of system():
my $in = __FILE__;
run \@cat, \$in, \$out, \$err, timeout( 10 ) or die "cat: $?";
say "\$out = $out";
say "\$err = $err";
say "\$in  = $in";
```

However, the output is not correct:

```
con@con-VirtualBox:~/Scripts$ perl ipc_run.pl
$out = ipc_run.pl
$err = 
$in  = ipc_run.pl
```

`$out` is just the file name, when it should be the contents of the file.  This should be doing `cat ipc_run.pl` on the command line

How can I get `$out` to display the output as it should?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are passing the filename as the `STDIN` to `cat`, and since you didn't pass it any arguments, it is repeating that to the output; that's how `cat` works. Instead pass the filename as an argument:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use IPC::Run qw(run timeout);

my @cat = ('cat', __FILE__);
run \@cat, \undef, \my $out, \my $err, timeout( 10 ) or die "cat: $?";
```